# Is it possible to make a piece of code atomic (C#)?

Tags: c#, multithreading

When I said atomic, I meant set of instructions will execute without any context switching **to another thread on the same process** (other kinds of switches have to be done of course). The only solution I came up with is to suspend all threads except currently executed before part and resume them after it. Any more elegant way?

The reason I want to do that is to collect a coherent state of objects running on multiple threads. However, their code cannot be changed (they're already compiled), so I cannot insert mutexes, semaphores, etc in it. The atomic operation is of course state collecting (i.e. copying some variables).

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Suspending all the other threads is a dangerous way to go about things and you could end up with a deadlock where your awake thread tries to do something and one of the suspended threads has a lock of some kind held it can't ever release.

Comment: I've never heard the word atomic in this context. I only know it as part of ACID, the definition of a transaction. By the way, why do you need this?

Comment: Individual IL operations are atomic.  There are very few classes (one is Interlocked) that support atomic operations.  Other than that, nope.  And I don't see the point.

Comment: @yodaj007: Not all IL operations are atomic.  For example, storing or fetching a `long`/`ulong`/`double` on a 32-bit host is not atomic.

Comment: @cdhowie, Ah, right.  I bow before your wisdom.

Comment: @Roger, Stefan, yodaj007: I tried to detail the reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some atomic operations in the [Interlocked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd78zt0c.aspx) class but it only provides a few very simple operations. It can't be used to create an entire atomic block of code.

I'd advise using locking carefully to make sure that your code will still work even if the context changes.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can use [locks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx), but you can't prevent context switching exactly. But if your threads lock on the same object, then the threads waiting obviously won't be running, so there's no context switching involved since there's nothing to run.

You might want to look at [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163715.aspx) too.

Comment: Locks don't necessarily "without any context switching to another thread on the same process"

Comment: Yeah, I realized that afterward; made a slight change, but I guess it still doesn't answer the question well.

Answer (score 1):

No.  You can surround a block of code with a Monitor to make it thread-safe, but you cannot make general code snippets atomic.

```
object lck = new object();

lock(lck)
{
     // thread safe code goes in here

}
```

Comment: Why is this being downvoted?  Is my answer somehow incorrect?

Comment: @yodaj007: It wasn't me that downvoted but I have a guess as to why: your code (if blindly copied and pasted) will create a new object each time it is run and therefore won't actually synchronize anything.

Comment: Ugh.  Yes, this is true, the way I typed it.  It wasn't blindly copy/pasted though.  I typed it up in Notepad++.

Comment: @Mark: Even if he did it as a static member variable, the question is how to back to old DOS days with dedicating all of the CPU time to some instructions. So he didn't read the question and I down-voted too. But I'm gonna remove it now.

Comment: @Xaqron: More or less, however the main idea is to get another threads not to mess with data being collected. Other threads and all threads belonging to another processes are free to take over CPU :)

Comment: @MarkByers But why a new object would be created each time? At first, i thought, lck should be sttaic, but then i looked at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx , so Amy's way seems legit. Have no idea, why answer is downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's against multi-tasking.

Unless very simple operations like incrementing ... which are not subject of your question.

Comment: Incrementing a number isn't atomic either unless you're talking about the Interlocked class.  I can provide code to demonstrate it, if desired; make a question on SO and I'll answer it.

Comment: I talked generally, and that simple operations are like `Interlocked.Increament()` and a few more.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to obtain a global state from a shared memory composed of a collection (array) of atomic one reader/multi writer registers. The solution is simple but not trivial. You can read the algorithm published in the paper "atomic snapshots of shared memory" or you can read the chapter 4 from the art of multiprocesor programming book, there you can get ideas on the implementation on the java language, of course, once you are familiarized with the idea you should be able to transport it to any other language. Sorry if my english is not well enough.